# What canon evidence is there that Stormtroopers are/are not still clones?

Tags: star-wars, canon, stormtroopers

Reading this article about [The Top 10 Reasons Proving Boba Fett Killed Luke Skywalker's Aunt and Uncle](https://www.toptenz.net/top-10-reasons-boba-fett-killed-luke-skywalkers-aunt-and-uncle.php), my nerd-rage started flaring as they claimed that Stormtroopers were still Fett-Clones 20 years after the rise of the Empire.

As I started thinking about it, I realized that everything I had read saying that Modern-Day Stormtroopers *not* being clones was from the EU - C Level books or games.

One of the quotes often cited for backing the idea that the Stormtroopers are clones comes from Princess Leia:

> Aren't you a little short for a Stormtrooper?

But through the movie, paying close attention, Stormtroopers are often shown to be slightly different heights. One even hits his head in the doorway while others walk through uninjured.

Is there any <strike>G Canon</strike> fully canon (non-Legends/Infinities) evidence to support the idea that Stormtroopers are, or are not still clones at the time of Episode IV?

Comment: "One of the quotes often cited for backing the idea that the Stormtroopers are clones comes from Princess Leia" - this is completely bogus. It can just as easily be explained by minimal height requirements for STs

Comment: @DVK "this is completely bogus." I didn't say I agreed with it - just that I've heard it used as an argument to back the idea.

Comment: In Episode II Lucas saw fit to have Jango hit his head as he entered Slave I, either as an in-joke, or to imply (at least some) Stormtroopers in Episode IV are clones. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCyZO9QjfL4

Comment: Doesn't this answer it's own question? "But through the movie, paying close attention, Stormtroopers are often shown to be slightly different heights." If there are Stormtroopers of different heights, aren't they not clones?

Comment: @keen, possibly, but that may have just been an issue of extras versus something more official. I'm also not sure if the clones' heights varied at all based on age/type.

Comment: Clones wouldn't have to be the same height. Part of development is genetic, the other is environmental. Better nutrition, avoiding childhood diseases could lead to different results.

Comment: By the time of A New Hope, their marksmanship has severely deteriorated... Clearly the sign of twenty years of clone degeneration. /s

Comment: The height difference could be age related. The clones are shown as kids as well.

Comment: "One of the quotes often cited for backing the idea" -- I'd say that this quote suggests the exact opposite: if stromtroopers were clones and therefore had uniform height, then Leia noticing the height discrepancy would *immediately know* that Luke wasn't a stormtrooper.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Clones were phased out of the Stormtrooper Corps and replaced with non-clone volunteers.

### *Star Wars: Rebels* (out-of-universe confirmation)

[Pablo Hidalgo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo) has confirmed that **the stormtroopers are *not* clones but are instead volunteers**, as of the events in *Star Wars Rebels* (which occur 5 years before the events of Episode IV). The explanation given is that the production of clones has been phased out, and since the clones age at twice the rate of normal humans<sup>1</sup> they are too old to serve as stormtroopers. They have been replaced with non-clone volunteers who are patriotic and loyal to the Empire. Video evidence can be found on [Youtube (starting at about 2:56 into the video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=J_6zOjTrI5w#t=176).

<sup>1</sup>The clones' age acceleration is not new, but it was not known (outside of Legends) whether production continued after the Clone Wars or not.

### Star Wars: *Rebels (in-universe confirmation)*

One year before The Force Awakens' first teaser trailer was released, the Star Wars: Rebels' sixth episode, [Breaking Ranks](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Breaking_Ranks), main plotline featured Ezra Bridger infiltrating an Imperial Training Academy on Lothal. The fact that Ezra is not a clone and the cadets depicted are all humans of varying skin color and phenotypes demonstrates that the Empire had transitioned to the training of regular citizenry by this point in history.

[image: Ezra Bridger infiltrates a class of Imperial Stormtrooper cadets]

### *Tarkin* (in-universe confirmation)

The [canon novel *Tarkin*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_%28novel%29) includes an incident where a group of stormtroopers are seen by Moff Tarkin without their helmets. The stormtroopers are led by a Kamino clone sergeant but all the other troopers are non-clone recruits. Here is the relevant quote (the stormtroopers are loading Darth Vader's meditation chamber onto Tarkin's ship):

> When the stormtrooper operating the equipment accidentally allowed the
> flattened sphere to bang against the edge of the cargo hold’s
> retracted hatch, Vader stamped forward with his gloved hands clenched.
>
> “I warned you to be careful!” he shouted up at the trooper.
>
> “My apologies, Lord Vader. Wind shear from—”
>
> “Excuses won’t suffice, Sergeant Crest,” Vader cut him off. **“Perhaps you are aging too quickly to remain on active duty.”**
>
> Tarkin couldn’t make sense of the remark until **he realized that Crest’s was a face he had seen countless times during the war—the face of an original Kamino clone trooper. The bare-headed others comprising Vader’s squad were human regulars who had enlisted after the war.**
>
> <sub>**p. 94**</sub>

[The novel takes place about 5 years after the end of the Clone Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121079/31936), so clone production evidently stopped at the end of the Clone Wars and within 5 years the clones were becoming too old to be useful as soldiers. Hence, they were replaced by non-clone volunteers.

Comment: To add to this fine answer. The newest rebels episodes also comment a bit on this and show that the former clone troopers have quite some negative oppinion on these "so called storm troopers" and see themselves as WAY superior to them

Comment: Additionally, the new canon book "Battlefront: Twilight Company" also shows us 'human' stormtroopers (as opposed to clones)

Comment: Also, had the Stormtroopers all been clones, Luke being "a little short for a stormtrooper" would have been a dead giveaway.

Comment: A few years later: in Star Wars: The Bad Batch, which takes place between The Clone Wars and Rebels, it's explicitly shown over several episodes that clones are being replaced by recruits.

Answer (score 26):

The accent is evidence against.  In the prequel trilogy, all of the clones speak with the same accent - Jango Fett's.  By Episode IV they're speaking with different accents, and Lucas apparently (and I'm being cautious about saying this in case he ever comes across this site and starts getting ideas...) never saw fit to re-overdub their voices (which I should note he *did* with Boba Fett's, so it's obviously something he *does* see as being significant).

For slightly more conclusive evidence, in Episode IV we actually see Stormtroopers with their faces exposed!  Where?  Watch the "technological terror" scene again, and look at the door guards closely - although blurred, you can see that their complexion is different to Jango Fett's.  How can I say that they're Stormtroopers?  Easily, I just read [the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111232554/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/anh-script.shtml):

> Eight Imperial senators and generals sit around a black conference table. **Imperial stormtroopers** stand guard around the room. Commander Tagge, a young, slimy-looking general, is speaking.

(My emphasis)

Of course, we're talking G-Canon here so we don't care if the EU has another name for them; G-Canon says that they're Stormtroopers and G-Canon shows their faces exposed.

Comment: Watching Big Bang Theory last week, they were waiting for Sheldon so they could watch Star Wars. Howard said 'if you don't hurry up George Lucas'll have changed it again' :-)

Answer (score 17):

There are a number of sources for the Stormtroopers becoming primarily recruits:

- *Star Wars: Battlefront II* (Video Game: C-canon) tells how after the [Battle of Kamino](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Kamino_%28Imperial_Period%29), clones were no longer viewed favorably. But it is notable that it says "cloned from a variety of templates", implying that clones were still heavily in use

> The bounty hunter left after the battle was over, he said something about tracking down a smuggler on Tatooine. After the Kamino uprising, the Emperor decided that an army of genetically identical soldiers was too susceptible to corruption. Future troopers would be cloned from a variety of templates. Though the 501st itself remained pure, the rest of the Imperial Army gradually became more and more diverse. We never really got used to the new guys.

- *Star Wars: The Force Unleashed II* (Video Game: C-canon) has some mentions of the difference between clones and recruits, as noted [here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stormtrooper#The_Galactic_Civil_War). Most notably, from a databank entry:

> Commander Cody, a first generation clone of Jango Fett and a veteran of the Clone Wars, found stormtrooper recruits to be absolutely intolerable. Due to the significant decrease in the Imperial Military's operational effectiveness and his own feelings of nostalgia over the Republic's "army of one man," Cody viewed enlisted troopers as incompetent idiots, all of whom he would have gladly sacrificed for just one real clone trooper.

- [Star Wars Insider 96](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_96) (?-canon) says that "By 0 BBY, roughly one-third of the stormtroopers were clones based on the Fett template, while recruits steadily became the majority within the Stormtrooper Corps."
- Two sources (*[The Essential Guide to Warfare](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Warfare)*, and *[Galaxy At War](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_at_War)*, page 95) (?-canon) note that "Service in the Stormtrooper Corps was open to both Human men and women, but female stormtroopers were an extremely rare sight under Palpatine's reign and on average there were never more than three female stormtroopers within a whole legion." (Obviously a female could not have been a clone of Jango Fett)
- [*The Essential Atlas*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas) (?-canon) tells how "Due to the loss of Kamino and its cloning facilities, as well as many other cloning centers throughout the galaxy, clone stormtroopers became a rare commodity that the Empire could no longer afford to sustain."

So there don't appear to be any G-canon sources that I've been able to find, but there are a number of varying EU sources, primarily video games and guides that provide backing for recruit troopers.

Answer (score 3):

Some may still be, in fact, clones. But not all are. Han Solo tried to join into the Imperial rank-and-file as a pilot, but washed out. Seems to me that the clones were a necessary evil at the time for the REpublic/Empire during Episodes 2 and 3, but by the time Episode 4 comes around, it has been 19+ years since the start of the Empire. Undoubtedly, it would be cheaper to accept volunteers and conscripts as oppose to cloning hundreds of thousands test-tube babies. It would explain the attrocious aim, the lack of effective battle tactics, and the fact that they can be beaten by Muppets (sorry, *Ewoks*). If there are clones left, and they are still producing them, it would seem to me that they would be used in a shock trooper scenario (suchs a invasions, martial law situations, and other high-stress combat events) while the piddly dum-dums are regaled to guarding a door (badly), admitting that these were not the droids they were looking for, and running away from a solo armed smuggler.

Ignore the obvious moon-sized plot hole, and it all makes perfect sense up until the next retcon for Episode 7.

Comment: "Han Solo tried to join into the Imperial rank-and-file as a pilot, but washed out." This is c-canon only, if I'm not mistaken? Or is there a g-canon source for this? Also, regarding your criticisms regarding the performance of Stormtroopers during Episodes IV - VI, [Jeff's answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4059/1359) is definitely worth a read!

Comment: This is nice reasoning but unfortunately Han's past isn't G-canon, is it?

Comment: I've read the novelizations and scripts for eps 4-6 and can't recall Han's past in the Imperial academy ever being mentioned. It's in the C canon books that that's explored. I'm also asking more specifically about the Stormtroopers since we can clearly see that the officers are not clones.

Answer (score 0):

If you played "star wars republic commando" and "Battlefront 2" it showed in commando, that the original and grunt clones were wiped out and eliminated as shown in the battlefront 2 campaign where you lead a squad against the kamino clone facilities because there was "Intel" that they started to clone for the purpose of assisting the jedi after order 66. As of republic commando where you play as the elite clones "commandos" it is hinted that some commandos which are still clones, dissipear, or join the empire to assist and train volunteers and mercenaries for the emperors new army. Was there still clone commandos in the empires armies later on? We will never know. At the beginning there still was though. Who else was more qualified to fast train volunteers to become storm troopers and pilots? lol

Comment: Republic Commando and Battlefront 2 are both C-Canon. I'm specifically asking for G-Canon information only.

Comment: i don't know what C-canon and G-canon mean. i'll look into that.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars