# Why there are only humans for service on Darth Vader's ships?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious

Recently I watched Star Wars Episode 4 and 5 and I noticed that on Darth Vader's ships (the Death Star, the Executor) and other Empire ships there are only human species as crew.

There are no aliens or other species on board, other than the brief scene with the bounty hunters.

**Is there any special reason behind this?**

Comment: Because Moff Tarkin is an enormous racist.

Comment: @Richard but its on vader's hand that who can join crew and serve his/ her service - I think

Comment: @Richard Ok, Got it. Thanks :) may the force be with you (y)

Comment: I think the dupe answers this nicely; The Empire even has a policy of "human first".

Comment: Hmmm, Ok Ok @Richard, Thanks. Today is Episode 6th's Turn. :D

Comment: To be fair, we don't see any *unmasked* aliens (aside from the Dianoga) on the ship. Since it's now established that [Stormtroopers are not clones during the OT](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41198/5184), we don't yet have full confirmation that there's no Trandoshan or something somewhere in there. Also, we really only see unmasked people on the bridge or in conference rooms. For all we know, they've got Ugnaughts in the trash room just like Cloud City.

Comment: @phantom42: The *Legends* continuity established that there were Wookiee slaves and non-human traders - including at least one Twi'lek - on the first Death Star. The traders had set up shop in a cantina Tarkin let them operate for morale purposes, from memory.

Comment: @Richard - Tarkin may be a LOT of things, but "enormous" is absolutely NOT one of them