# Why are the storm troopers in The Force Awakens not the original clones?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the new *Star Wars* movie there is a black stormtrooper, but I thought that all stormtroopers were clones. I have tried to look this up but with no success.

Why are clones no longer used as stormtroopers?

Comment: Clone != storm trooper

Comment: Also note that the character in question says he was taken from his family at a young age and forced to serve. He's clearly not a clone and I think it's reasonable to expect that none of the other Stormtroopers in TFA are clones. I dimly recall some conversation involving Phasma about the way Stormtroopers were selected/whatever.

Comment: Finn talks about his abduction and conditioning. Also, after Finn goes AWOL, Kylo Ren makes a remark to Hux about how maybe he should consider going back to clones.

Comment: The original clones would be ~60 years old in normal years, but ~120 by their reckoning thanks to their accelerated aging.  Would you consider a bunch of feeble super centenarians a threat?

Comment: While a duplicate, I do want to point out that the OP is not challenging that the stormtroopers are clones, but rather asking when they stopped using the clones.  He clearly accepts that clones are no longer in use.  And, if you only watch the movies, you have no idea that clones age 2x as fast as humans.

Answer (score 6):

You're confusing *[Clonetroopers](http://www.starwars.com/databank/clone-troopers)* and *[Stormtroopers](http://www.starwars.com/databank/stormtroopers)*.

Clonetroopers were used by the Republic during the Clone Wars, and were all genetic clones of [Jango Fett](http://www.starwars.com/databank/jango-fett).

The Empire used Stormtroopers, which were made up, at least in part, of non-clones. This is explicitly shown during the show *Star Wars: Rebels*, where we see recruits working towards becoming Stormtroopers.

See also:

- [Why Did the Empire Discontinue the Clone Trooper Program?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11432/5184)
- [Are the Empire (or First Order) not using clones any more? If not, why?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111963/5184)

Answer (score 2):

In Star Wars Rebels Season 2, the initial encounter with Captain Rex had him remarking that the Emperor had retired the clones. Stormtroopers are now fully birth-born recruits. 13 years would have passed before the first batch of clones was commanded to execute Order 66, another 19 years before the Battle of Yavin, 3 years from then to the Battle of Endor and then 30 years to The Force Awakens. Considering accelerated ageing, the first batch of clones would be 130 years old by then. The Fett clones would all be dead.

As for the reason why clones aren't used anymore? They are expensive. And the original clones weren't willing executors of Order 66 - they are loyal to the Jedi and the Republic but inhibitor chips overrode their natural loyalties. They were then released (Kanan mentioned clones later telling him they had chips in them, that they had no choice. This indicates he encountered clones who snapped out of it and are no longer willing to go on a Jedi killing spree) from control and are clearly traumatic and unhappy over what they were tricked into doing. Not a good idea to keep these kind of guys around to rule your new Empire.

By the time of The Force Awakens, the First Order has access to less resources than before. Cloning had indeed been considered as an option for how to raise a new army of stormtroopers, but ultimately the decision was made to kidnap babies and raise them in a brainwashed environment instead. Not using clones was a conscious decision of the First Order.

Comment: It always seemed to me like the clones were bred to be perfect soldiers who always followed orders. I *really* don't like that they had "inhibitor chips" and without them, they would have disobeyed a direct order from their commander in chief.

Comment: I thought it was 19 years between order 66 and the battle of yavin, not 13, then another 19.  That would have made Luke almost 30 by the time of ANH came about.

Comment: @Thunderforge Because the Jedi has successfully taught the clones individuality and free will, and inspired loyalty and trust, no matter how deeply loyalty to Palpatine was inculcated into their genes. Palpatine anticipated that, so the inhibitor chips were there to make sure the Jedi can't jeopardise the success of Order 66. It's different in Legends, but the Legends version seem even more unbelievable - would Palpatine tell millions of clones the truth from birth and expect none of them to inform the Jedi, considering some of them did defy Order 66?

Comment: @CBredlow Read again. After the first batch of clones are born, 10 years would pass before they were deployed to Geonosis. The Clone Wars ended 3 years later with Order 66, and then 19 years from then till the Battle of Yavin.

Comment: From the clones' perspective, the Supreme Chancellor public ally states that the Jedi just made an assault on his life that he barely escaped from (and it permanently disfigured him). The text for Order 66 in Legends says that should the Jedi act against the interests of the Republic (which attempting to "assassinate" their leader clearly is) they should dispatch them. Given the information they had, the clones either felt they were protecting the Republic from traitors, of they were "just following orders." I think this was intended to have historical parallels of real soldiers e.g. Nazis.

Comment: Also, Order 65 was about detaining and possibly executing the Supreme Chancellor, and there were other similar orders. So having an order to take out Jedi wasn't as unusual, just another contingency. And of course, Jedi couldn't teach millions of Jedi free will, so concientious objectors were few. Hopefully, that explains the Legends viewpoint better. I like it better, but I'll agree to disagree if you prefer the other version.

Comment: @Thunderforge The existence of Order 65 was politically motivated: Palpatine needed Order 66 to eliminate the Jedi, but the Jedi would be suspicious of the existence of such an executive order, so Order 65 is there to disguise it as part of a system of checks and balances against abuse of power, which the Jedi will be distracted by and therefore accept. In reality, nobody can execute Order 65 because the approving authorities are nominated by Palpatine and staffed with his loyalists.

Comment: @Thunderforge As for the clones in Legends, they had been trained from birth to prepare for the eventual execution of Order 66. Even from the First Battle of Geonosis, they already knew they will one day kill their generals. The 501st Legion told us that. That's why I felt Legends was equally unbelievable: Palpatine would never have tolerated millions of clones susceptible to mind tricks knowing his true plan. At least, with the inhibitor chips, efforts were made to disguise their true purpose. The Legends version was too great a loophole in Palpatine's masterpiece.