# Why do the numbers of the storm troopers in Finn's group skip some?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, stormtroopers

In FN-2187's 4 man squad there is also FN-2199, FN-2000, and FN-2003. Shouldn't the numbers be consecutive like FN-2000, FN-2001, FN-2003, and FN- 2004?

Comment: Simple answer would be the squad would be made up AFTER they get their designations. I don't have any evidence for this so leaving as a comment

Comment: If the training for 1st order Troopers is anything like the training scenes in "Star Wars: Rebels" then it's likely they had wastage from cadet deaths, people washing-out and/or being siphoned off for Officer training / specialist training and lesser duties.

Comment: Even in real world militaries, numbers are given in sequence, true, but after boot camp everyone is deployed randomly to their permanent postings. If teams are formed during boot camp before passing out, then the instructors will have an influence in ensuring team synergy is optimised overall. In such a system, the best combination for a recruit to team up with is unlikely to be the next four guys in serial number. In Finn's case, the best cadets may have been handpicked and formed into teams, slated to eventually join Kylo's flagship.

Comment: One correction: [they're not clones](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114483/why-are-the-storm-troopers-in-the-force-awakens-not-the-original-clones)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the Stormtroopers are given their numbers very early in training, and then matched up with other troopers to create squads. But the numbers are not consecutive because they do not necessarily work well with those troops. Even then, some troops in the squad may not be able to pass tests, live fire exercises, vigorous training, or may be moved up or down like to sanitation duty or officer training(Source for training and officer training: Star Wars Rebels, and Before the Awakening). Also, because of Captain Phasma's direct oversight and FN-2187's top scores as a soldier his 4 man squad was probably a little more elite.

Comment: Also some will die and get replaced, there is no way to avoid that even if they obsessively kept the consecutive numbers grouped together.