# In Star Wars Rebels, how can the kids at the Stormtrooper Academy know their parents and have a name?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, stormtroopers, first-order

I thought that Finn in *The Force Awakens* said that stormtroopers were taken into the academy at an age they don't know their parents and didn't even know their name? So how could those kids in Rebels know their parents and names?

Comment: Finn is part of the First Order. In SW: Rebels it is still the Empire... they possibly have different rules...

Comment: One question per question post, please. I've edited out your tangential question about some stormtroopers being better shots. Please ask that as a separate question if you wish to have it answered.

Answer (score 21):

You are confusing stormtroopers of the First Order with stormtroopers of the Galactic Empire.

[*Star Wars Rebels*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) is set five years before the events of the original trilogy, so these stormtroopers serve the [Galactic Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Empire) (the one ruled by Emperor Palpatine). The [Galactic Empire phased out clones from the Stormtrooper Corps at the end of the Clone Wars and used volunteers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72400/31936). Since [these stormtroopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper) are volunteers, they joined as adults and obviously know their parents and have a name.

The [First Order](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Order) is the successor state to the Galactic Empire. [Its stormtroopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_%28First_Order%29), like Finn, were conscripted at birth.

Comment: Also Timothy Zahn's Allegiance has some info on the matter. Stormtroopers of the Galactic Empire such as Daric LaRone or Saberan Marcross knew their parents and relatives, I can recall.

Comment: @VerpinZal Yes. It's a good book, too, but it's Legends.