When did Storm Troopers stop being clones?
I'm very certain when I was younger stormtroopers were supposed to be clones. I remember they all had the same voice, build, and height (Leia asking Luke "aren't you a little short to be a stormtrooper?) and I seem to remember Luke saying something about the clone wars, implying clones were a thing and the stormtroopers were them. I also remember reading the "Dark Empire" comics where Palatine tried to return by cloning.
When did the narrative change so that stormtroopers were regular conscripts? Was it in "Star Wars:Rebels"? I thought the idea of the Empire filling their expendable ranks (i.e. their army, fighter wings, and anybody with their face covered) with disposable men was a great idea.

Does https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41198/what-canon-evidence-is-there-that-stormtroopers-are-are-not-still-clones answer your question?

I don't think Lucas ever really meant stormtroopers to be clones - a comment on Luke's height could merely reference that there is a minimum height requirement to be a stormtrooper (or Leia being defiantly acerbic).

probably when one banged his head on the doorway...

While it’s possible to conclude from the original trilogy that stormtroopers are clones, all evidence suggesting they are is circumstantial at best and requires making conjectures that that media does not provide clear evidence for. The required evidence did not exist until Episode II and III came out. In particular, the mention of the Clone Wars in ANH just indicates that cloning exists, it says nothing about the circumstances of the cloning, and the height comment has any number of other explanations.

Yeah in the 1980s and early 1990s, nobody I knew talked about stormtroopers being clones at all. Seems like a companion question might be, "when did stormtroopers start being clones?" I didn't even think the mention of "The Clone Wars" in episode IV meant clones fought it in any more than I think "The War of the Roses" was fought by flowers.

First off: Stormtroopers were not "always" meant to be clones (there's no mention of it in any draft of ANH that I'm aware of), however the thinking on this behind the scenes did seem to change at least once, if not twice.
It's difficult to pin down an exact definitive source for any of this since it's scattered across numerous passing mentions in interviews, commentary tracks, panel discussions and the like with the various people involved (directly or otherwise), over the course of the last few decades.
That said, so far as I understand it the idea that the Stormtroopers were clones dates back to the prequels at the very least. Lucas stated this numerous times, and even including a gag in AotC where Jango bonks his head getting into his ship, as a reference to the notorious gaff in ANH; suggesting (jokingly, of course) that it's an inherited genetic trait.
From what I've gathered over the years, this changed at some point during the run of 'Clone Wars' as Lucas reportedly noticed young fans having grown up watching the animated show, and holding a lot of affection for the clones, would get upset when then came to watch the original movies and see their heroes acting as bad guys.
Solid information on this next part is tough to come by for obvious reasons; but the idea that the clones would instead have been decommissioned and essentially abandoned by the Empire as a "lost generation" following the end of Clone Wars seems to have been something he developed for the un-produced 'Star Wars: Underworld' live-action TV-Show. Ostensibly this would have been because they exhibited far more independent thought and individuality, thanks partly to the encouragement of their Jedi Generals.
Subsequent stories seem to have remained faithful to this idea, and indeed a surprisingly amount of other 'Underworld' material has made it into later stories, so it seems to be well regarded, at least internally at LF.
As to when the idea of Stormtroopers as clones first occurred to Lucas . . . well that's really hard to say. There does seem to be some indication that it might come from sometime around the production of tESB. It's fairly well established that the Boba Fett character design originally started life as a new kind of "Super-commando" Stormtrooper, and that the expense of the costume meant the idea was scaled back to just the one character, while the former concept evolved into what we now know as 'Snowtroopers'. What does this have to do with clones? Well it's a little nebulous, but there's been mentions by Lucas over the years that at various points he thought maybe Boba Fett was a left-over clone from the clone wars, or at least his armour was a relic of that time. This seems to be the seed if the idea that culminated in Boba's involvement in AotC. So there may have been some kind of connection there prior to the prequels, if only at the back of his mind.

I don't see any option to reply to any specific comment but I think Kris makes a lot of sense. Yes I was wondering when the out-of-universe answer was because I grew up with old school Star Wars and was very much under the impression the storm troopers were clones. To me the fact the storm troopers were now regular people felt like some kind of betrayal of what was originally written.

Funny, i and others at the time, knowing only the original star wars, never thought of them as clones, just a regular army made up of either conscripts or professionals.

@JohnDoe I think the main take away here is that whatever changes happened, they happened because the person that created this universe altered his thinking back and forth over time as he elaborated on concepts in newer stories; as is the prerogative of any creator. Nobody's intent is being subverted. Whatever assumptions one might have made, Lucas himself made no explicit or overt connection between the (very briefly mentioned) clone wars, and the Stormtroomers prior to making the prequels. The earlier scripts are agnostic on this point as it wasn't terribly relevant to those stories.

The Bad Batch explores some aspects of this, slowly phasing out clones and replacing them with conscripts. Several episodes focuses exclusively on what to do with the clone vets as well as how the empire started recruiting regular people to become troopers.
In short, shortly after the end of the Clone Wars, the empire started replacing clones.

This answers from within the narrative of Star Wars, but I think the OP is asking for an out-of-universe explanation. I also think they're starting from a false premise (that Stormtroopers were supposed to be clones in the original 1977 movie).

Makes a bit of sense lore-wise as well. Getting them all from a single facility that's capable of inserting control chips is great if you're looking to subvert the government. Once you are the governnment, and you've taken over that way, no way would you want to keep a known potential security hole like that around.
