# Why bring Luke to his family on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, obi-wan-kenobi

So I just finished the Star Wars series (again), and because I watched the original trilogy first, I ended with Revenge of the Sith, which brought a question to my mind.

Why in heaven's name did Yoda and Obi-Wan decide to bring Luke Skywalker back to his family on Tatooine?

I mean they were just talking about the fact that the twins need to be separated, they need to be kept hidden, and they need to disappear until the right time comes... Senator Bail Organa of Alderaan agreed to take Leia as both he and his wife had long wanted to adopt a girl. Since there is hardly any connection between the Skywalker family and the Senator of Alderaan, it makes sense that Leia would have been safe there.

And then suddenly Yoda tells Obi-Wan to take Luke to his family on Tatooine. I mean Anakin Skywalker, aka Darth Vader *came from* Tatooine. He *was born* and *lived there* for his first 10 years. He met Owen Lars and his girlfriend and future-wife Beru. His *mother* was buried *right outside* the doorway of the Larses' home. Why did Yoda and Obi-Wan think Luke would be safe and hidden somewhere so ingrained into Anakin's history?

I have read some other writings that say Darth Vader would never have wanted to return to, or even think about, Tatooine, where he spent the first ten years of his life as a slave. Also, since Padme was fitted-up to look like she had died still pregnant (as shown in the funeral scene in Revenge of the Sith), Vader and Sidious would not have known that the children survived, so they wouldn't have looked for Luke or Leia.

But seriously, there have got to be better places to hide someone. Sending Luke back to live with his family, and by extension, Anakin's family, right where Anakin's mother was buried (and we all know how much Ani loved his mom) seems like a huge risk...

Comment: See also [How was Obi-Wan Kenobi able to hide his light side presence from Vader and the Emperor?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/how-was-obi-wan-kenobi-able-to-hide-his-light-side-presence-from-vader-and-the-e) and [If they were trying to keep Luke safe from Vader, why would they let him keep the Skywalker name?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/if-they-were-trying-to-keep-luke-safe-from-vader-why-would-they-let-him-keep-th)